# How to add a block of code after a list of items?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

I've been trying to get the proper output for the following situation, but I couldn't manage to make it. The problem appears with bulleted list and numbered lists. Here is the problem:

### With numbered list

1. Do something;
2. Do something else.

   ✔ ~/src/linux $ git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline --reverse ./include/media/v4l2-clk.h
       ff5430de70e8137daccecfa1211509f95fcc8d25 [media] V4L2: add temporary clock helpers
       cf326dfebe612bf56c83d8fca7a7c1d1584c061f [media] V4L2: add v4l2-clock helpers to register and unregister a fixed-rate clock
       774cc4c289152bfb77806ccae722a9ae2d29dd02 [media] V4L2: add a v4l2-clk helper macro to produce an I2C device ID
       a37462b919e1368ea3cf4bb0cbdb00ca8e76959c [media] V4L: remove clock name from v4l2_clk API
       4f528afcfbcac540c8690b41307cac5c22088ff1 [media] V4L: add CCF support to the v4l2_clk API
       ac2841f3b80170415b63ae5ca8ea417f65244604 [media] v4l2-clk: add new macro for v4l2_clk_name_of()
       3d83078a081a2bac7639d09404d85085368c8b66 [media] v4l2-clk: add new definition: V4L2_CLK_NAME_SIZE
       68d9c47b1679ec8d55a005d39fc7a958ece82095 media: Convert to using %pOF instead of full_name

   ✔  ~/src/linux $ git describe ff5430de70e8137daccecfa1211509f95fcc8d25
   v3.10-rc6-391-gff5430d

### Without bullets

Do something

Do something else

```
 ✔ ~/src/linux $ git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline --reverse ./include/media/v4l2-clk.h
    ff5430de70e8137daccecfa1211509f95fcc8d25 [media] V4L2: add temporary clock helpers
    cf326dfebe612bf56c83d8fca7a7c1d1584c061f [media] V4L2: add v4l2-clock helpers to register and unregister a fixed-rate clock
    774cc4c289152bfb77806ccae722a9ae2d29dd02 [media] V4L2: add a v4l2-clk helper macro to produce an I2C device ID
    a37462b919e1368ea3cf4bb0cbdb00ca8e76959c [media] V4L: remove clock name from v4l2_clk API
    4f528afcfbcac540c8690b41307cac5c22088ff1 [media] V4L: add CCF support to the v4l2_clk API
    ac2841f3b80170415b63ae5ca8ea417f65244604 [media] v4l2-clk: add new macro for v4l2_clk_name_of()
    3d83078a081a2bac7639d09404d85085368c8b66 [media] v4l2-clk: add new definition: V4L2_CLK_NAME_SIZE
    68d9c47b1679ec8d55a005d39fc7a958ece82095 media: Convert to using %pOF instead of full_name

✔  ~/src/linux $ git describe ff5430de70e8137daccecfa1211509f95fcc8d25
v3.10-rc6-391-gff5430d
```

---

I've tried it on GitHub and get the same outcome, so I won't mark this as a bug. What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: tl:dr; on the dupe: indent the code twice if it's part of the list (can't do that via the toolbar unfortunately, so manually add spaces/use a code editor/something else), or add something between the code and the list (e.g. a blank html comment) if it's not part of the list.

Comment: Looks like it thanks! I didn't find that post before posting unfortunately. thanks!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth For multiple indents: Indent using the editor, add 1 character random character to the front of a line, indent using the editor again, repeat as required. Remove random added characters. I wouldn't say that's particularly effective, but it works. Although I wouldn't indent code into a list when it's not part of the list.

Comment: @Dukeling that would be a bug then?

Comment: @Aif What's a bug? There's only 1 indent button for both indenting and unindenting, and you don't really want it to randomly add more or less spaces depending on the context, so it probably works as intended. You could post a feature request asking for 2 buttons instead (or find the one that was probably already posted somewhere here).

Comment: I mean if you "add 1 character random" and "remove random added characters", it looks like it's a specific workaround to make it work. Hence a (maybe?) bug.